# How do I enable &>/dev/null by default for all sh/bash commands?

Tags: bash, stderr, null

Is there a way to make `&>/dev/null` the default behavior in a sh/bash script? I' rather not have to appended this to every command within the console, not an *.sh script.

I'm looking to make a global setting...or at least a custom alias of some sort, but one that makes any command and every command, auto-append `&>/dev/null` to the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why, on earth, would you want to do this? Output exists for a reason, and though it is helpful to sometimes get rid of that output, making it the default seems very odd to me.

Comment: Why?, I need to know.

Answer (score 6):

Add `exec &>/dev/null` in the beginning of bash script

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is suddenly a bash script, too.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell:

```
exec >/dev/null
# still shows the prompt
exec 2>/dev/null
# now the prompt is gone, too

# restore stdout
exec >/dev/tty
# restore stderr
exec 2>/dev/tty
```

Comment: you can make the prompt go by redefining PS

Comment: @richard I did not mean only what the shell prints automatically but also the commands you type (which are not affected by `PS1`).

Comment: @John1024 That's strange: I thought that it should work with `/dev/tty`. I tested that and it didn't work thus I used the other way. If I test it again now it works... No idea what may have gone wrong before.